# Adding image to screen according to user's slide

Tags: android, image, slide

I would like to display a transperent PNG of a "light" line shape according to user's sliding path.
I'd like to make similar effect like Fruit Ninja has, and leave a track after user slides his finger.

I already have the x,y points of his finger - using `onTouch` method, and checking the x,y on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` but how do i draw an image that will be tilted and displayed at those positions? all i know is to add padding/margin to an image, not how to place it using x,y, or how to rotate it..

Answer (score 0):

For positioning and rotating use a canvas (getSurfaceHolder().lockCanvas()) and draw inside it using drawBitmap.

```
public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Matrix mtx, Rect dst, Paint paint)
```

the matrix can include the rotation:

```
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.postRotate(90);
```

Comment: I don't really understand how to use your suggestion.  I have an Activity and an XML with the design.   Where do i "plug" the slashing image? i create a new Bitmap from res? i add it to the XML with invisible mode?

Comment: And my code doesn't recognize  getSurfaceHolder().lockCanvas()   i guess its SurfaceView code or something, not an Activity methods

Answer (score 0):

You might want to se the code from API demos, [FingerPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html).